# Iterate through memory editing each byte

Tags: assembly

I'm writing assembly code that prompts the user for a string of lower-case characters then outputs the same string with all UPPER-CASE characters. My idea is to iterate through the bytes starting at a specific address and subtract 20H (turns a lower case to upper-case) from each one until I reach a byte with a specific value. I'm fairly inexperienced with Assembly so I'm not sure what the syntax for such a loop would look like.

Can anyone provide some sample code or direct me where I can find examples of such syntax?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not just study the output of `gcc -S` for a C implementation of the solution to your problem?

Comment: How familiar are you with ASM? Because I'm not seeing the problem if you know just the very, very basics (mov, add, jz)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, a string is terminated with a null (0x00 in hex). Assuming this is what you choose to do, here's some sample code. I'm not sure which assembler you're using, or even which syntax, but this x86 code that should work in MASM:

```
mov cl, 0             ; cl is the counter register, set it to
                      ; zero (the first character in the string)

start:                ; Beginning of loop
  mov al, bytes[cl]   ; Read the next byte from memory

  cmp al, 0           ; Compare the byte to null (the terminator)
  je end              ; If the byte is null, jump out of the loop

  sub al, 20h         ; Convert to upper case
                      ; A better solution would be: and al, 0DFh

  ; Output the character in al

  add cl, 1           ; Move to the next byte in the string
  jmp start           ; Loop
end:
```

Comment: Addressing modes can only use full-width registers like `rcx` (or `ecx` in 32-bit mode).  You should also mention that this is (an attempt at) indexing into a static array called `bytes`.  That name is close to MASM's operand-size specifier `byte ptr`; e.g. `mov al, byte ptr [bytes + ecx]`

Answer (score 1):

Well, one concise (but not optimal for performance on current processors) choice would be:

- have a counter of some type to control the loop
- point ds:si and es:di at the beginning
- do a lodsb, and al, dfh, stosb sequence in the loop